# Why is this python script crashing my computer

Tags: python

When I run this script in terminal I can receive data serially, but eventually my entire computer freezes up. Could someone explain why this is happening?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sys import argv
from msppg import Parser
import serial

if len(argv) < 2:

    print('Usage: python %s PORT' % argv[0])
    print('Example: python %s /dev/ttyUSB0' % argv[0])
    exit(1)

def handler(pitch, roll, yaw):
    print(pitch, roll, yaw)
    port.write(request)

pitch, roll, yaw = 5, 15, 20
port = serial.Serial(argv[1])
parser = Parser()
request = parser.serialize_ATTITUDE_Request()
parser.set_ATTITUDE_Handler(handler)

def cycle(value):
    return (value + 1) %360

while True:

   print port.read(1)
   if port.read(1) != None:
       port.write(parser.serialize_ATTITUDE(pitch, roll, yaw))
   pitch = cycle(pitch)
   roll  =  cycle(roll)
   yaw   =  cycle(yaw)
```

Comment: Any output in dmesg or syslog?

Comment: maybe because of infinite loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone explain why this is happening?

`while True:` without a `break`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the app is trying to read from a physical port and your `while` loop is constantly reading.  This behavior will look up your computer as there are no waits or callbacks for reading the data.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the port.read(1) line. According to [PySerial's Documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html?highlight=read#serial.Serial.read) you're specifying  that you only want one byte to be read from the USART hardware buffer. However, if there isn't a byte to be read PySerial by default will wait for some data, causing your program to "freeze".

My suggestion is to add a timeout arg to the port init line (where 12 means 12 seconds, it can be anything you want)

```
port = serial.Serial(argv[1], timeout=12)
```